# SQLite Alternatives

Tags: php, sqlite, lighttpd

I am looking for an alternative for sqlite.  I have an application that has lighttpd built into it and serves php scripts to interact with multiple instances of another application.  All architectural questions aside, for some reason, the person who wrote this chose to use sqlite as the database for the php scripts -- to store and retrieve information for the scripts themselves.  As such, it appears we have locking issues.  To deal with that the programmer used stuff like this:

```
$executed = $storeDB->exec($updateSQL);
while($executed === FALSE && $i<10) {
    $storeDB->close();
    $storeDB = new SQLite3('C:/Path/path2/LightTPD/store.db');
    $pragmaDB = "PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL";
    ($storeDB->exec($pragmaDB));
    $executed = $storeDB->exec($updateSQL);
    $i++;
}
```

I understand why sqlite was chosen as it can be copied over and over, does not need to installed as a server, and is very small.  However, with multiple instances of an application hitting those php scripts, sometimes concurrently, I can see that it is causing some problems:  some information retrieval operations fail and some data is not updated.  I get Warnings in the log like this.

An UPDATE statement

```
[07-Mar-2015 21:03:44 UTC] PHP Warning:  SQLite3::exec(): database is locked in C:\Path\path2\LightTPD\htdocs\ProcessRequest.php on line 194
```

and

A SELECT statement

```
[07-Mar-2015 21:22:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  SQLite3::query(): Unable to prepare statement: 5, database is locked in C:\Path\path2\LightTPD\htdocs\ProcessRequest.php on line 151
```

I say all of that to ask, does anyone have any comparable alternatives to sqlite for this situation?  I listed the reasons it was chosen to begin with, but the primary need is that it be able to be copied, though I can get around that if necessary.

Comment: Couldn't you just define a `busyTimeout`? For reference : http://php.net/manual/fr/book.sqlite3.php#99290

Comment: My apologies, I did not know that function existed.  It says that it works per connection.  Since I have multiple instances of an application hitting my ProcessRequest.php, each ProcessRequest.php has its own connection.  I can just give busyTimeout a value of 1 or 2 seconds, it should handle it better as these are very small queries and there should never be more than 3-6 at a time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can afford to wait for the lock to clear, you can use the sqlite [busy timeout](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.busytimeout.php).